# JSON Data does not show on List Android

Tags: java, android, json, list, adapter

I'm trying to retrieve a data from a web server and show it on a `List` in `Android`, It seems that I am receiving the data correctly but it never appears on the list, I have a confusion with the adapter and I don't know if it is really doing what I want it to do, although I am receiving some sort of errors from the `JSON` data it says type does not match, could be this the reason?

Following is the file from which I call the adapter

```
public class MyKinstFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView ;
private Button newsButton, documentsButton;
private SimpleAdapter adpt;
//ArrayList<String> listItems= new ArrayList<String>();

/*private static String[] MOBILE_MODELS = {"iPhone 6","Nexus 6","Moto G","HTC One","Galaxy S5","Sony Xperia Z2","Lumia 830","Galaxy Grand 2"};*/
private static String[] MOBILE_MODELS = {"cachampo","champs","champi","champu","Galaxy S5","Sony Xperia Z2","Lumia 830","Galaxy Grand 2"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mykinst_layout, container, false);

    initWidgets(rootView);  


    return rootView;
}

public void initWidgets(View rootView){
    adpt = new SimpleAdapter(new ArrayList<News>(), rootView.getContext());

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adpt);
    listView.setClickable(true);



    newsButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsButton);
    newsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newsButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            documentsButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            (new AsyncListViewLoader()).execute("http://kinst.gizmomen.com/api/v1/feeds/");

        }
    });

}

//GET news from webserver
private class AsyncListViewLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<News>> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<News> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        adpt.setItemList(result);
        adpt.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Getting Data");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<News> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<News> result = new ArrayList<News>();

        try {
                URL u = new URL(params[0]);

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                //read
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                while (is.read(b) != -1)
                    baos.write(b);

                String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());

                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);
                for(int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    result.add(convertNews(arr.getJSONObject(i)));
                }

                return result;
        }   
        catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    private News convertNews(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        String id = obj.getString("id");
        String title = obj.getString("title");
        String message = obj.getString("message");
        String imageUrl = obj.getString("image_url");
        String location = obj.getString("location");

        return new News(id, title, message, imageUrl, location);
    }

}

}
```

and here is the Adapter I customize for the object "News"

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> { 

private List<News> newsList;
private Context context;

public SimpleAdapter(List<News> newsList, Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newsList);
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.context = ctx;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



public int getCount() {
    if(newsList != null)
        return newsList.size();
    return 0;
}

public News getItem(int position) {
    if (newsList != null)
        return newsList.get(position);
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (newsList != null)
        return newsList.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if(v==null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    News n = newsList.get(position);
    TextView tle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tle.setText(n.getTitle());

    TextView msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);
    msg.setText(n.getMessage());

    TextView loc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.location);
    loc.setText(n.getLocation());

    TextView iUrl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgurl);
    iUrl.setText(n.getImgURL());

    return v;
}

public List<News> getItemList() {
    return newsList;
}

public void setItemList(List<News> itemList) {
    this.newsList = itemList;
}


}
```

And the log cat I am getting is this:

> 05-20 21:47:02.690: W/System.err(741): org.json.JSONException: Value {"results":[{"message":"
>
> just it</p>","id":10,"title":"new 4","location":[87,89,90,91,92,94],"image_url":"feed_images/Screen_Shot_2015-05-15_at_4.13.47_pm_Rv9LCka.png"},{"message":"
>
> any content</p>
>
> second line</p>
>
> end</p>","id":9,"title":"the third one","location":[87,89,90,91,92,94],"image_url":"feed_images/Screen_Shot_2015-04-28_at_4.40.20_pm.png"},{"message":"
>
> with image too</p>","id":8,"title":"another one","location":[87,89,90,91,92,94],"image_url":"feed_images/Screen_Shot_2015-04-28_at_4.35.51_pm.png"},{"message":"
>
> new with image</p>
>
> ok?</p>","id":7,"title":"with image","location":[87,89,90,91,92,94],"image_url":"feed_images/Screen_Shot_2015-05-15_at_4.13.47_pm.png"}],"previous":null,"count":4,"next":null} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
>   05-20 21:47:02.690: W/System.err(741):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   05-20 21:47:02.690: W/System.err(741):  at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:91)
>   05-20 21:47:02.730: W/System.err(741):  at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:103)
>   05-20 21:47:02.760: W/System.err(741):  at com.javacodegeeks.android.tablayout_with_fragments.MyKinstFragment$AsyncListViewLoader.doInBackground(MyKinstFragment.java:139)
>   05-20 21:47:02.760: W/System.err(741):  at com.javacodegeeks.android.tablayout_with_fragments.MyKinstFragment$AsyncListViewLoader.doInBackground(MyKinstFragment.java:1)
>   05-20 21:47:02.830: W/System.err(741):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   05-20 21:47:02.830: W/System.err(741):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   05-20 21:47:02.830: W/System.err(741):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   05-20 21:47:02.830: W/System.err(741):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   05-20 21:47:02.830: W/System.err(741):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   05-20 21:47:02.830: W/System.err(741):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   05-20 21:47:02.878: W/System.err(741):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

However I don't think that the JSON data is the problem, Please help I'll appreciate it forever

Comment: If `JSONResp` is the json shown in the stacktrace, then that means it's a JSON Object and not an Array

Comment: Problem is 10000% your JSON parsing.  Read the exception.

Comment: I have been looking for it but I'm not able fix it, I am trying like this
<code>
String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());
     
     JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(JSONResp);
     JSONObject newsDetails = jobj.getJSONObject("results");
     
      String id = newsDetails.getString("id"); 
      String title = newsDetails.getString("title");
      String message = newsDetails.getString("message");
      String imgUrl = newsDetails.getString("img_url");
      String location = newsDetails.getString("location"); </code>

Comment: @Hank Thanks Hank, I am trying to change it to a JSON Object however it still keep showing the same error 
`String JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());
     
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(JSONResp);
     JSONObject newsDetails = jobj.getJSONObject("results");
     
String id = newsDetails.getString("id"); 
String title = newsDetails.getString("title");
String message = newsDetails.getString("message");` Any help

Comment: `"results"` is a JSON Array so `JSONObject newsDetails = jobj.getJSONObject("results");` will throw an exception

Comment: I fix it finally, it was the the JSON parsing indeed, Thanks to all!